# Push Notifications Active App

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that I am building which utilizes push notifications.  These are working perfectly.

I am currently expanding upon my push notifications, so that from the lock screen when you slide right, it will open up the specific part of the app.  This works perfectly as is.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSDictionary *data = [userInfo objectForKey:@"custom data"];
if (self.shouldGiveNotification) {
    if ([[data objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:requestStatusMentionRequestType]) {
        // mentioned in status, need to pull up the app with the single status controller...
        NSLog(@"WE ARE HERE");
        UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;

        StatusViewController *pvc = [[StatusViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatusViewController" bundle:nil];
        pvc.statusID = [data objectForKey:@"eid"];
        pvc.standalone = YES;
        NavigationViewController *nav = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pvc];
        [vc presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

}
```

I wrote the bool property so that when the server sends the notification, if the app is currently active it won't run the code.  This came back to bite me in the butt a little, in that if the app is currently active, and I slide down from the top and click on a notification and the app does not open the corresponding place of the app.

So need to figure out how to adapt this to check that it is a notification that was clicked as opposed to one that hits this method just because the app is active.  And I've no clue how to do it any any ideas are helpful, and i'll share whatever code I need to share.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a check in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` can help you identify when the notification is tapped from the notification center and your application was launched from it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if (launchOptions) {
        NSDictionary * data = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        //do something with this data based on your usecase
    }
    return YES:
}
```

For the other method that you have already implemented when you receive remote notification, should help you capture PUSH notifications when your application is already running.

Let me know if this helps, or If I misunderstood your original question.

Comment: I have essentially the same code in there and it works.  My problem exists when the app is running and is in the foreground.  If I drag down from the top and select a push notification ( that was delivered when the app was in the background ) it does nothing ( because of my boolean value that is NO everywhere except when you enterBackground).  Getting rid of the boolean doesn't work, as when i get a PN the app would automatically process and follow it.

Comment: Then you can handle the else part in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" where you receive a notification and you have added a check to see if app is running.

Comment: But if the app is active, and I select a notification from dragging down from the top, it wouldn't process what it needs to.  That's my issue...

Comment: If your application is in foreground and you slide down the notification center from top and select the previous PUSH, the application won't be launched but you should still get "didReceiveRemoteNotification" being called. I cannot validate this point at the moment, but you can run this usecase and add proper logging to each method to see which methods are invoked.

Comment: Problem is, I need to specifically filter out somehow NEW notifications within that method vs ones clicked from an actual notification in the notification center...  Otherwise, all new notifications will instantly show the content when we don't want them to

Answer (score 0):

To run specific code only when push notification intializes the application you should use [*application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or [*UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification)
The data of Push Notification is passed in dictionary (launchOptions in method or userInfo in notification)

According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) it is discouraged tu use *- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*

> IMPORTANT
>
> For app initialization, it is highly recommended that you
>   use this method and the application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   method and do not use the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method, which
>   is intended only for apps that run on older versions of iOS.